# how do I find out where the configuration file for apt is located?

Tags: apt, regular-expression, configuration

I looked at the usual culprit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` but there is no configuration file for apt therein so it has to be somewhere else. Running reportbug against apt does give the dump but it doesn't tell where the configuration file resides. I know have used `apt-config dump` but it isn't easy or tell where it is sourcing the file from. Is there a way to figure it out ? I am sure a grep should give the secret but what needs to be grepped, am not sure, am not familiar with perl. I am on testing, running `apt 1.3~rc4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration is split in multiple files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

For me it is:

```
├── apt.conf.d
│   ├── 00aptproxy
│   ├── 00CDMountPoint
│   ├── 00trustcdrom
│   ├── 01autoremove
│   ├── 01autoremove-kernels
│   ├── 05etckeeper
│   ├── 20apt-show-versions
│   ├── 20listchanges
│   ├── 20packagekit
│   ├── 50apt-file.conf
│   ├── 70debconf
│   └── 99synaptic
```